# Python Problems with if statement

Tags: python, conditional-statements, if-statement

I have a problem with this piece of code.
Somehow if we put in `'register'` or `'Register'` as input, it goes to the register function, but after it prints the else: `Aswell ("Bad input")`; I have made more of these but cant find the fault in this one.

Please help me. Thanks! Here's my code:

```
def Boot(): 
        print "Type 'Login' + accountname to login."

        x = raw_input("> ")
        Name = x.split()

        if x == "Register" or x == "register":
            print "Registerbla"

        if Name[0] == "Login" or Name[0] == "login":
            print "Loginblabla"
        else:
            print "Bad input"
```

So what I see after input is:
Registerbla
Bad input

Comment: I think you want "elif Name..." instead of "if Name..."

Comment: In editing your post, I notice that you have spaces and tabs in your source.  I hope that's just from trying to get it to display properly in stack overflow's renderer -- However, if it isn't, that's a particularly bad thing in python code.  You can always run python with `python -t script.py` to find out if you're mixing spaces and tabs in a bad way.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `else` portion of your if statement. Without it, you actually check two separate if statements: the register section and the login/bad input section. Instead, you should use `elif`:

```
    if x == "Register" or x == "register":
        print "Registerbla"
    elif Name[0] == "Login" or Name[0] == "login":
        print "Loginblabla"
    else:
        print "Bad input"
```

Also, consider changing your statements to check against lowercase, like

```
if x.lower() == "register":
    # Now any capitalized variant of register will work!
```

Answer (score 1):

when you type in `register` or `Register`

`if Name[0] == "Login" or Name[0] == "login":`

evaluates to false, printing `Bad input`